# Express JS inline Code

Tags: node.js, express

i want to know if it is possible to send client information in express without socket.io but like socket.io, with the view template pug?

So something like that:

```
body
    .mainclass
```

Answer (score 0):

To send client information to express, you should send http requests from the client to your server. It can be done using forms (html) or ajax requests (js).
SocketIO is usually used to send information from the server to the client.

Comment: so there is no way to send it like in socket io with an emit or something like that?